# How do I make Scrapy crawl the next page on this site?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Here is the code I have so far.  I want to loop through all the remaining pages on this site and scrape each one, then put all the output into a .csv file.

```
import scrapy
# No unneeded imports

class BillingsorgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "billingsorg"
    allowed_domains = ["billings.org"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.billings.org/agents/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # iterate through each of the realtors
        for staff in response.css('div.staff-capsule'):
            # gather contact information for each realtor
            item = {
                'name': staff.xpath('.//h3//text()').get().strip(),
                'phone': ''.join(staff.xpath('.//div[@class="staff-phone"]//text()').getall()).strip(),
                'email': staff.xpath('.//div[@class="staff-email"]//a/@href').get(),
                'company': ''.join(staff.xpath('.//div[@class="staff-company"]//text()').getall()).strip()
            }
            print(item)  # print the item here in the scope of the method
            yield item   # yield to output processor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do for pagination is grab the current page element by using the xpath for `a[@class="btn btn-info"]`  and then use a relative xpath from the current page link to get the sibling element which would be the next page. Then you should compare the two links to know when you have reached the last page.  Then put the link in a new scrapy request and yield it back to the scheduler.

For example:

```
import scrapy

class BillingsorgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "billingsorg"
    allowed_domains = ["billings.org"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.billings.org/agents/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for staff in response.css('div.staff-capsule'):
            item = {
                'name': staff.xpath('.//h3//text()').get().strip(),
                'phone': ''.join(staff.xpath('.//div[@class="staff-phone"]//text()').getall()).strip(),
                'email': staff.xpath('.//div[@class="staff-email"]//a/@href').get(),
                'company': ''.join(staff.xpath('.//div[@class="staff-company"]//text()').getall()).strip()
            }
            yield item
        current_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-info']")
        next_page = current_page.xpath("./following-sibling::a/@href").get()
        if next_page and next_page != current_page.xpath('./@href').get():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page))
```

OUTPUT

```
{'name': 'Cari Baxter', 'phone': '406-671-1675', 'email': 'mailto:cari.baxter59105@gmail.com', 'company': 'Real Estate Hub LLLP'}
2023-02-28 13:31:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/7/>
{'name': 'Cari Baxter', 'phone': '406-671-1675', 'email': 'mailto:cari.baxter59105@gmail.com', 'company': 'Real Estate Hub LLLP'}
{'name': 'Linda Beach', 'phone': '406-425-0808', 'email': 'mailto:beach.lin@gmail.com', 'company': 'LHB Appraisal Service'}
2023-02-28 13:31:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/7/>
{'name': 'Linda Beach', 'phone': '406-425-0808', 'email': 'mailto:beach.lin@gmail.com', 'company': 'LHB Appraisal Service'}
{'name': 'Dallas Bedford', 'phone': '406-839-3311', 'email': 'mailto:dallas@bedfordandassociates.com', 'company': 'Real Estate Services'}
2023-02-28 13:31:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/7/>
{'name': 'Dallas Bedford', 'phone': '406-839-3311', 'email': 'mailto:dallas@bedfordandassociates.com', 'company': 'Real Estate Services'}
{'name': 'Kylee Beery', 'phone': '406-366-6399', 'email': 'mailto:kyleebeery@gmail.com', 'company': 'MB Realty'}
2023-02-28 13:31:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/7/>
{'name': 'Kylee Beery', 'phone': '406-366-6399', 'email': 'mailto:kyleebeery@gmail.com', 'company': 'MB Realty'}
{'name': 'Robert Beery', 'phone': '406-478-3568', 'email': 'mailto:rjbeery@hotmail.com', 'company': 'Yellowstone Real Estate Professionals'}
2023-02-28 13:31:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/7/>
{'name': 'Robert Beery', 'phone': '406-478-3568', 'email': 'mailto:rjbeery@hotmail.com', 'company': 'Yellowstone Real Estate Professionals'}
2023-02-28 13:31:21 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/> from <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8>
2023-02-28 13:31:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/> (referer: https://www.billings.org/agents/page/7/)
{'name': 'Nicole Beeton', 'phone': '406-690-2569', 'email': 'mailto:nicole@nicolebeeton.com', 'company': 'Western Skies Real Estate'}
2023-02-28 13:31:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/>
{'name': 'Nicole Beeton', 'phone': '406-690-2569', 'email': 'mailto:nicole@nicolebeeton.com', 'company': 'Western Skies Real Estate'}
{'name': 'Connie Begger', 'phone': '406-850-3269', 'email': 'mailto:conniebeggermt@gmail.com', 'company': 'Select Property Brokers'}
2023-02-28 13:31:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/>
{'name': 'Connie Begger', 'phone': '406-850-3269', 'email': 'mailto:conniebeggermt@gmail.com', 'company': 'Select Property Brokers'}
{'name': 'Vicki Beley', 'phone': '406-853-8545', 'email': 'mailto:vicki@davesmithrealty.com', 'company': 'Dave Smith Realty'}
2023-02-28 13:31:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/>
{'name': 'Vicki Beley', 'phone': '406-853-8545', 'email': 'mailto:vicki@davesmithrealty.com', 'company': 'Dave Smith Realty'}
{'name': 'Carissa Belless', 'phone': '406-855-2156', 'email': 'mailto:realestatebycarissa@gmail.com', 'company': 'Magic City Real Estate'}
2023-02-28 13:31:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/>
{'name': 'Carissa Belless', 'phone': '406-855-2156', 'email': 'mailto:realestatebycarissa@gmail.com', 'company': 'Magic City Real Estate'}
{'name': 'Angela Belus', 'phone': '406-853-5034', 'email': 'mailto:angela.belus@outlook.com', 'company': 'MB Realty'}
2023-02-28 13:31:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/>
{'name': 'Angela Belus', 'phone': '406-853-5034', 'email': 'mailto:angela.belus@outlook.com', 'company': 'MB Realty'}
{'name': 'Jon Bengochea', 'phone': '406-263-5662', 'email': 'mailto:jben@nemont.net', 'company': 'United Insurance & Realty'}
2023-02-28 13:31:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/>
{'name': 'Jon Bengochea', 'phone': '406-263-5662', 'email': 'mailto:jben@nemont.net', 'company': 'United Insurance & Realty'}
{'name': 'James Benner', 'phone': '406-265-2182', 'email': 'mailto:james.benner@exprealty.com', 'company': 'eXp Realty, LLC'}
2023-02-28 13:31:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/>
{'name': 'James Benner', 'phone': '406-265-2182', 'email': 'mailto:james.benner@exprealty.com', 'company': 'eXp Realty, LLC'}
{'name': 'Earl Bennett', 'phone': '406-861-1700                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                        406-245-4349', 'email': 'mailto:earl_b_59105@yahoo.com', 'c
ompany': 'Bennett Realty'}
2023-02-28 13:31:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/>
{'name': 'Earl Bennett', 'phone': '406-861-1700                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                        406-245-4349', 'email': 'mailto:earl_b_59105@yahoo.com', 'c
ompany': 'Bennett Realty'}
{'name': 'Kim Bennett', 'phone': '406-539-4924', 'email': 'mailto:kim@terrawestern.com', 'company': 'Terra Western Associates'}
2023-02-28 13:31:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/>
{'name': 'Kim Bennett', 'phone': '406-539-4924', 'email': 'mailto:kim@terrawestern.com', 'company': 'Terra Western Associates'}
2023-02-28 13:31:22 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/> from <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9>
2023-02-28 13:31:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/> (referer: https://www.billings.org/agents/page/8/)
{'name': 'Mona Bennett-Abelseth', 'phone': '406-671-2876', 'email': 'mailto:monamovesmt@gmail.com', 'company': 'eXp Realty, LLC'}
2023-02-28 13:31:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/>
{'name': 'Mona Bennett-Abelseth', 'phone': '406-671-2876', 'email': 'mailto:monamovesmt@gmail.com', 'company': 'eXp Realty, LLC'}
{'name': 'Heidi Benson', 'phone': '406-794-8890', 'email': 'mailto:heidi.b@kw.com', 'company': 'Keller Williams Yellowstone Properties'}
2023-02-28 13:31:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/>
{'name': 'Heidi Benson', 'phone': '406-794-8890', 'email': 'mailto:heidi.b@kw.com', 'company': 'Keller Williams Yellowstone Properties'}
{'name': 'Jeffrey Bent', 'phone': '406-579-4977', 'email': 'mailto:jeffbent7@yahoo.com', 'company': 'Obsidian Realty Group'}
2023-02-28 13:31:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/>
{'name': 'Jeffrey Bent', 'phone': '406-579-4977', 'email': 'mailto:jeffbent7@yahoo.com', 'company': 'Obsidian Realty Group'}
{'name': 'Andrew Beres', 'phone': '406-425-3236', 'email': 'mailto:andy@cbthebrokers.com', 'company': 'Coldwell Banker The Brokers RL'}
2023-02-28 13:31:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/>
{'name': 'Andrew Beres', 'phone': '406-425-3236', 'email': 'mailto:andy@cbthebrokers.com', 'company': 'Coldwell Banker The Brokers RL'}
{'name': 'Jeff Berger', 'phone': '406-970-4034', 'email': 'mailto:jeffbsellsmt@gmail.com', 'company': 'NextHome Peaks to Prairie'}
2023-02-28 13:31:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/>
{'name': 'Jeff Berger', 'phone': '406-970-4034', 'email': 'mailto:jeffbsellsmt@gmail.com', 'company': 'NextHome Peaks to Prairie'}
{'name': 'Amy Berry', 'phone': '406-861-1884', 'email': 'mailto:amyberrymt@gmail.com', 'company': 'Metro, REALTORS L.L.P'}
2023-02-28 13:31:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/>
{'name': 'Amy Berry', 'phone': '406-861-1884', 'email': 'mailto:amyberrymt@gmail.com', 'company': 'Metro, REALTORS L.L.P'}
{'name': 'Brandon Bertrand', 'phone': '406-671-4609', 'email': 'mailto:brandonmbertrand@msn.com', 'company': 'Trusthaven Real Estate'}
2023-02-28 13:31:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/>
{'name': 'Brandon Bertrand', 'phone': '406-671-4609', 'email': 'mailto:brandonmbertrand@msn.com', 'company': 'Trusthaven Real Estate'}
{'name': 'Samantha Best', 'phone': '406-242-0296', 'email': 'mailto:sbestrealitymt@kw.com', 'company': 'Keller Williams Yellowstone Properties'}
2023-02-28 13:31:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/>
{'name': 'Samantha Best', 'phone': '406-242-0296', 'email': 'mailto:sbestrealitymt@kw.com', 'company': 'Keller Williams Yellowstone Properties'}
{'name': 'Twyla Best', 'phone': '406-591-9191', 'email': 'mailto:twylab10@gmail.com', 'company': 'Metro, REALTORS L.L.P'}
2023-02-28 13:31:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/>
{'name': 'Twyla Best', 'phone': '406-591-9191', 'email': 'mailto:twylab10@gmail.com', 'company': 'Metro, REALTORS L.L.P'}
2023-02-28 13:31:23 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/> from <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10>
2023-02-28 13:31:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/> (referer: https://www.billings.org/agents/page/9/)
{'name': 'Neil Beyer', 'phone': '406-272-6568', 'email': 'mailto:neil@elephasre.com', 'company': 'eXp Realty, LLC'}
2023-02-28 13:31:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/>
{'name': 'Neil Beyer', 'phone': '406-272-6568', 'email': 'mailto:neil@elephasre.com', 'company': 'eXp Realty, LLC'}
{'name': 'Alexis Bidlake', 'phone': '406-702-0914', 'email': 'mailto:alexis.bidlakec21@gmail.com', 'company': 'Century 21 Hometown Brokers'}
2023-02-28 13:31:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/>
{'name': 'Alexis Bidlake', 'phone': '406-702-0914', 'email': 'mailto:alexis.bidlakec21@gmail.com', 'company': 'Century 21 Hometown Brokers'}
{'name': 'John Bidlake', 'phone': '406-860-4567                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                        406-656-5407', 'email': 'mailto:john@billingsinsurance.com'
, 'company': 'Bidlake & Associates'}
2023-02-28 13:31:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/>
{'name': 'John Bidlake', 'phone': '406-860-4567                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                        406-656-5407', 'email': 'mailto:john@billingsinsurance.com'
, 'company': 'Bidlake & Associates'}
{'name': 'Rhonda Bidlake', 'phone': '406-860-4568', 'email': 'mailto:rhonda@billingsinsurance.com', 'company': 'Bidlake & Associates'}
2023-02-28 13:31:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/>
{'name': 'Rhonda Bidlake', 'phone': '406-860-4568', 'email': 'mailto:rhonda@billingsinsurance.com', 'company': 'Bidlake & Associates'}
{'name': 'Jerred Bies', 'phone': '406-600-0449', 'email': 'mailto:jerred@mccalldevelopment.com', 'company': 'McCall Real Estate'}
2023-02-28 13:31:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/>
{'name': 'Jerred Bies', 'phone': '406-600-0449', 'email': 'mailto:jerred@mccalldevelopment.com', 'company': 'McCall Real Estate'}
{'name': 'Jeanne Bilile', 'phone': '406-672-1757', 'email': 'mailto:jeanneb1757@gmail.com', 'company': 'Keller Williams Yellowstone Properties'}
2023-02-28 13:31:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/>
{'name': 'Jeanne Bilile', 'phone': '406-672-1757', 'email': 'mailto:jeanneb1757@gmail.com', 'company': 'Keller Williams Yellowstone Properties'}
{'name': 'Alexandra Blair', 'phone': '406-210-5490', 'email': 'mailto:AlexandraBlairRealEstate@gmail.com', 'company': 'Real Estate Hub LLLP'}
2023-02-28 13:31:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/>
{'name': 'Alexandra Blair', 'phone': '406-210-5490', 'email': 'mailto:AlexandraBlairRealEstate@gmail.com', 'company': 'Real Estate Hub LLLP'}
{'name': 'Sarah Blatchford', 'phone': '406-698-9080', 'email': 'mailto:ksblatchford@gmail.com', 'company': 'North Acre Real Estate'}
2023-02-28 13:31:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/>
{'name': 'Sarah Blatchford', 'phone': '406-698-9080', 'email': 'mailto:ksblatchford@gmail.com', 'company': 'North Acre Real Estate'}
{'name': 'Bernadette Blaylock', 'phone': '406-855-1397', 'email': 'mailto:bern15@aaarealty.com', 'company': 'A A A Realty, Inc.'}
2023-02-28 13:31:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/>
{'name': 'Bernadette Blaylock', 'phone': '406-855-1397', 'email': 'mailto:bern15@aaarealty.com', 'company': 'A A A Realty, Inc.'}
2023-02-28 13:31:24 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/> from <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11>
2023-02-28 13:31:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/> (referer: https://www.billings.org/agents/page/10/)
{'name': 'Chet Blotske', 'phone': '406-694-3065', 'email': 'mailto:chet@summitrealestatemt.com', 'company': 'Real Estate Hub LLLP'}
2023-02-28 13:31:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/>
{'name': 'Chet Blotske', 'phone': '406-694-3065', 'email': 'mailto:chet@summitrealestatemt.com', 'company': 'Real Estate Hub LLLP'}
{'name': 'Leanne Bodell', 'phone': '406-439-6904', 'email': 'mailto:leanne.bodell@bhhsmt.com', 'company': 'Berkshire Hathaway HomeServices Montana Properties'}
2023-02-28 13:31:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/>
{'name': 'Leanne Bodell', 'phone': '406-439-6904', 'email': 'mailto:leanne.bodell@bhhsmt.com', 'company': 'Berkshire Hathaway HomeServices Montana Properties'}
{'name': 'Jennifer Bodine', 'phone': '406-670-1676', 'email': 'mailto:jenniferbodinerealestate@gmail.com', 'company': 'Century 21 Hometown Brokers'}
2023-02-28 13:31:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/>
{'name': 'Jennifer Bodine', 'phone': '406-670-1676', 'email': 'mailto:jenniferbodinerealestate@gmail.com', 'company': 'Century 21 Hometown Brokers'}
{'name': 'Trevor Bogunovich', 'phone': '406-208-2280', 'email': 'mailto:sjbogun@live.com', 'company': 'Fenton Enterprises'}
2023-02-28 13:31:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/>
{'name': 'Trevor Bogunovich', 'phone': '406-208-2280', 'email': 'mailto:sjbogun@live.com', 'company': 'Fenton Enterprises'}
{'name': 'Kelly Bohnet-Erickson', 'phone': '406-861-5355                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                        406-656-9999', 'email': 'mailto:kelly.remax.reales
tate@gmail.com', 'company': 'RE/MAX Experts'}
2023-02-28 13:31:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/>
{'name': 'Kelly Bohnet-Erickson', 'phone': '406-861-5355                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                        406-656-9999', 'email': 'mailto:kelly.remax.reales
tate@gmail.com', 'company': 'RE/MAX Experts'}
{'name': 'Charity Boller', 'phone': '406-697-7036', 'email': 'mailto:cboller0976@gmail.com', 'company': 'Premier Realty'}
2023-02-28 13:31:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/>
{'name': 'Charity Boller', 'phone': '406-697-7036', 'email': 'mailto:cboller0976@gmail.com', 'company': 'Premier Realty'}
{'name': 'Lauren Bond', 'phone': '406-699-0200                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                        406-800-1222', 'email': 'mailto:agentlaurenbond@gmail.com',
'company': 'THE Agency Montana, LLC'}
2023-02-28 13:31:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/>
{'name': 'Lauren Bond', 'phone': '406-699-0200                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                        406-800-1222', 'email': 'mailto:agentlaurenbond@gmail.com',
'company': 'THE Agency Montana, LLC'}
{'name': 'Duncan Bonine', 'phone': '307-254-0533', 'email': 'mailto:duncan@dbwrealty.com', 'company': 'DBW Realty, Inc.'}
2023-02-28 13:31:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/>
{'name': 'Duncan Bonine', 'phone': '307-254-0533', 'email': 'mailto:duncan@dbwrealty.com', 'company': 'DBW Realty, Inc.'}
{'name': 'Brandon Booty', 'phone': '406-697-9622', 'email': 'mailto:brandon@41realtygroup.com', 'company': '41 Realty Group'}
2023-02-28 13:31:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/>
{'name': 'Brandon Booty', 'phone': '406-697-9622', 'email': 'mailto:brandon@41realtygroup.com', 'company': '41 Realty Group'}
2023-02-28 13:31:26 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/12/> from <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/12>
2023-02-28 13:31:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.billings.org/agents/page/12/> (referer: https://www.billings.org/agents/page/11/)
{'name': 'Brian Borich', 'phone': '406-861-4945', 'email': 'mailto:b.borich@yahoo.com', 'company': 'ERA American Real Estate'}
2023-02-28 13:31:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/12/>
{'name': 'Brian Borich', 'phone': '406-861-4945', 'email': 'mailto:b.borich@yahoo.com', 'company': 'ERA American Real Estate'}
{'name': 'Kevin Bos', 'phone': '406-661-3184', 'email': 'mailto:appraisalinsp2@gmail.com', 'company': 'Appraisal Inspection Services'}
2023-02-28 13:31:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/12/>
{'name': 'Kevin Bos', 'phone': '406-661-3184', 'email': 'mailto:appraisalinsp2@gmail.com', 'company': 'Appraisal Inspection Services'}
{'name': 'Troy Boucher', 'phone': '406-855-6998', 'email': 'mailto:montanareo@gmail.com', 'company': 'Boucher & Associates'}
2023-02-28 13:31:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/12/>
{'name': 'Troy Boucher', 'phone': '406-855-6998', 'email': 'mailto:montanareo@gmail.com', 'company': 'Boucher & Associates'}
{'name': 'Sarah Boughton', 'phone': '406-577-2520', 'email': 'mailto:sarah@buildingbozeman.com', 'company': 'Aspire Realty'}
2023-02-28 13:31:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/12/>
{'name': 'Sarah Boughton', 'phone': '406-577-2520', 'email': 'mailto:sarah@buildingbozeman.com', 'company': 'Aspire Realty'}
{'name': 'Chaney Bowen', 'phone': '406-633-5479', 'email': 'mailto:bowenhh@gmail.com', 'company': 'Coldwell Banker The Brokers'}
2023-02-28 13:31:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/12/>
{'name': 'Chaney Bowen', 'phone': '406-633-5479', 'email': 'mailto:bowenhh@gmail.com', 'company': 'Coldwell Banker The Brokers'}
{'name': 'Damon Bower', 'phone': '406-670-8555', 'email': 'mailto:dbcllcmt@gmail.com', 'company': 'Century 21 Hometown Brokers'}
2023-02-28 13:31:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/page/12/>
{'name': 'Damon Bower', 'phone': '406-670-8555', 'email': 'mailto:dbcllcmt@gmail.com', 'company': 'Century 21 Hometown Brokers'}
```

This is just partial results but you can see in the urls that it parses page 7 - 11